# Error 1, instaling quantmode package, R Studio

Tags: r, installation, package, quantmod

Thank you for taking the time to read my inquiry. I am trying to install the quantmod package in R and this is the result. Could you please help me understand the error and how to approach it? Thanks. (Macbook)

```
install.packages('quantmod')
also installing the dependencies ‘xts’, ‘zoo’, ‘TTR’

trying URL 'https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2018-08-01/src/contrib/xts_0.11-0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 533600 bytes (521 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 521 KB

trying URL 'https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2018-08-01/src/contrib/zoo_1.8-3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 856176 bytes (836 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 836 KB

trying URL 'https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2018-08-01/src/contrib/TTR_0.23-3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 309683 bytes (302 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 302 KB

trying URL 'https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2018-08-01/src/contrib/quantmod_0.4-13.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 142084 bytes (138 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 138 KB

Warning message:
In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libSM.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5.1-MRO/Resources/modules/R_X11.so
  Reason: image not found
* installing *source* package ‘zoo’ ...
** package ‘zoo’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include  -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2 -I/opt/X11/include   -fPIC  -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2 -I/opt/X11/include  -c coredata.c -o coredata.o
make: /usr/local/clang4/bin/clang: No such file or directory
make: *** [coredata.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘zoo’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5.1-MRO/Resources/library/zoo’
```

Comment: You have a really bizarre choice of repository.  Why use a 2018 edition of MRAN?

Comment: The other versions were not available for OS X

Comment: What version of OS X?

Comment: And what version of R?

Comment: I have R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02), Feather Spray. Microsoft R open 3.5.1. And, R Studio 2022.22.3

Comment: MacOS Catalina 10.15.7

Comment: Since you're on a pretty recent MacOS version, I'd recommend updating to the latest R.  Don't use Microsoft's build, use one from CRAN.r-project.org.  Then installing packages will just work.

Comment: Thank you, updating to the latest version from CRAN.r-project.org solved the issue